# Mongoose return document only if all sub-list elements match query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have simple structure like this:

```
{
_id: "4f23f23f432f43" //random _id
list: [
    {
        price: 8
    },
    {
        price: 13
    },
    {
        price: 17
    },
  ]
}
```

Above example is simple schema, which in base is list of few objects.
My problem is that I cannot get this to work:

```
dbQuery.menu = {
$elemMatch : {
    price: {
        $gte: request.query.minPrice
    }
  }
}
```

I need to find *only these documents* which all array elements matches this query. Meaning, return object only when it  has list which contains only values greater (or equal) than specified query value.

Now it returns all object which at least one list element is higher than specified value, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

If you want to add a `maxPrice` field to the query condition, it must be a an `$or`-combined statement, not  `$and`. Because `n >= minPrice && n <= maxPrice` should equal to `!(n < minPrice || n > maxPrice)`.

So the query now should look like:

```
YourModel.find({
  'list': { 
     $not: { 
       $elemMatch: {
         'price': {
            $or: [
              { $lt: request.query.minPrice },
              { $gt: request.query.maxPrice }
            ]
          }
       }
     }
  }
});
```

=====

(This is old answer)

Try this:

```
YourModel.find({
  'list': { 
     $not: { 
       $elemMatch: {
         'price': {
            $lt: request.query.minPrice
          }
       }
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! I still have another problem, I wanted to make also upper border, like "max". As i tried to add simple $gt to $not condition, it didn't worked. Should i also put there $and operator to require both conditions to be positive?

Comment: Or maybe other way.. Could you possibly help me with achieving filtering for two fields? $not didn't worked when i tried adding "$gt: request.query.maxPrice" for maxPrice upper range. Any idea?